# @RequestMapping in spring 3.2.8

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have this controller in Spring Framework MVC application (version 3.2.8) with 2 different methods: 1 for the GET and the other one for the POST

```
@Controller
public class ManageAccountController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger   (ManageAccountController.class);

    //private static final String USER="userBean"; 

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    /**
     * 
     * @param request the http servlet request.
     * @param model the spring model.
     * 
     */ 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/manageaccount.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm  (   @ModelAttribute("dataAccountCommand") final DataAccountCommand dataAccountCommand,
                                BindingResult result, 
                                HttpServletRequest request, 
                                Model model, 
                                Locale locale) {

        dataAccountCommand.setUserBean(getUser(request));

        return "registerAccountView";
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/saveaccount.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private String saveAccount  (   @ModelAttribute("dataAccountCommand") final DataAccountCommand dataAccountCommand, 
                                    BindingResult result,   
                                    HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    Model model, 
                                    Locale locale) {

        return "registerAccountView";

    }
}
```

the point is that when I put this in the browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices_admin/accounts/manageaccount.do
```

I am redirected to the jsp, but when I put

```
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices_admin/accounts/saveaccount.do
```

I have this error

```
URL: /devices_admin/accounts/saveaccount.do
???error404.error???
```

calling it from a jsp gives me the same result:

```
<form:form  commandName="dataAccountCommand" 
                name="dataAccountForm" 
                id="dataAccountForm"  
                method="post" 
                action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/accounts/saveaccount.do"                      
                htmlEscape="yes">

</form:form>
```

Comment: Could be that `Http.Post` works only when you submit a form ? Hitting trough browser makes by default `GET`.

Comment: No, then the error will be this one, not a 404: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not invoke a POST method directly from the URL bar of your Browser. If you put something in the URL bar you are invoking the GET mehtod.

Instead you have to create a page with a form

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices_admin/accounts/saveaccount.do">

...

</form>
```

Or you can install a REST client in your browser and make the call directly using the POST method.

Comment: I've tried as well: action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/accounts/saveaccount.do"

Comment: did you add the POST method in your form ?  can you add the JSP code ?